# VB.Net Dynamic chart creation. Layout help needed

Tags: vb.net, charts, logic

First off all, English is not! my first/native language.

For my internship @ this company I'm trying to collect some data. There are like 200 PC's in the network. All HP SFF PCs. All the pcs will be overwritten with a company disk image containing software and policies. They also get an bios update. But as the months go by these versions get outdated. Not that it is required to update the bios, we want to now which version in on which pc on which model.

There are several PC models. 
E.g. HP DC7600, HP 7700.

There are several bios versions.
E.g. 786G1 v01.10, 786G1 v01.16

I'm collecting this data with the following method. Every one has a network share to a certain disk.(Company documents).

For the **client** side I'm using WMI(Windows Management Instrumentation) to gather the information needed.

```
Sub RetrieveInfo()
    Dim _PCName As String = My.Computer.Name
    Dim _Info As String = vbNullString
    Dim _FileName As String = "G:\BiosVersion\" & _PCName & ".txt"
    Dim _ManagmentC As New ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem")
    Dim _Moc As ManagementObjectCollection = _ManagmentC.GetInstances

    For Each _Mo As ManagementObject In _Moc
        Dim Model() As String = Split(_Mo.Properties("Model").Value.ToString, " ")
        For i = 0 To Model.Length - 1
            If Model(i).ToLower.Contains("dc") Then _Info &= Model(i)
        Next
    Next

    _ManagmentC = New ManagementClass("win32_bios")
    _Moc = _ManagmentC.GetInstances
    For Each _Mo As ManagementObject In _Moc
        _Info &= "|" & _Mo.Properties("SMBIOSBIOSVersion").Value.ToString
    Next

    Try
        If IO.File.Exists(_FileName) Then
            IO.File.Delete(_FileName)
        End If
    Catch ex As IO.IOException
        _FileName = _FileName.Replace(_PCName, _PCName & "-" & New Random().Next(10, 10000))
    End Try

    IO.File.WriteAllText(_FileName, _Info)

End Sub
```

As you can see, this creates as text file in the share with the String PCName (e.g. PC1001).
It writes both the PC Model number & Bios version to the text file. (e.g. dc7900|786G1 v01.16)

---

For the **server** side, the chart building part, I'm doing the following.

```
Dim Path As String = "G:\BiosVersion\"
Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim PCModels As New List(Of String)
    Dim BiosVersions As New List(Of String)
    Dim Files As IO.FileInfo() = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path).GetFiles

    For Each File As IO.FileInfo In Files
        If File.Extension = ".txt" Then
            PCModels.Add(IO.File.ReadAllText(File.FullName).Split("|")(0))
            BiosVersions.Add(IO.File.ReadAllText(File.FullName).Split("|")(1))
        End If
    Next
    PCModels = RemoveDuplicates(PCModels)
    BiosVersions = RemoveDuplicates(BiosVersions)

    For i = 0 To chartBios.Series.Count - 1
        chartBios.Series.Remove(chartBios.Series.Item(i))
    Next

    Dim Dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    For Each Version As String In BiosVersions
        chartBios.Series.Add(Version)
        Dim Count As Integer = 0
        For Each File As IO.FileInfo In Files
            If IO.File.ReadAllText(File.FullName).Split("|")(1).ToLower.Trim = Version.ToLower.Trim Then
                Count += 1
            End If
        Next
        Dictionary.Add(Version, Count)
    Next

    For Each Entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In Dictionary
        chartBios.Series(Entry.Key).Points.AddY(Entry.Value)
    Next
End Sub

Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal inputList As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    Dim uniqueStore As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    Dim finalList As New List(Of String)()
    For Each currValue As String In inputList
        If Not uniqueStore.ContainsKey(currValue) Then
            uniqueStore.Add(currValue, 0)
            finalList.Add(currValue)
        End If
    Next
    Return finalList
End Function
```

chartBios = the chart control.

***Which results in the following:***
I can't post any images yet(Spam Prevention)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C42XB.jpg

What I'm trying to do is the following.
I have 3 Vars, Bios version, How many times each version is installed & model name.

## ***This is an example of the Chart layout that I want. Anyone has any idea on how to create this layout ? At runtime or static I don't care as long at it can be filled at Runtime.***

For each Bios version number there must be a bar for each PC Model with a label which represents the amount of times the bios version is installed.

Example:
I can't post any images yet(Spam Prevention)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgdrh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With MS Chart Controls, you can add multiple series to one chart, each series would represent your PC type where for each type you'd have BIOS version number and occurrence count.

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456769.aspx